# How to fix "Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass?

Tags: java

I've started a project using java 16 and I'm getting errors in the project all over the place:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6dfcffb5
```

It looks like the code I have from different version of java is not working in this particular
version. Any idea what I need to change maybe in the pojo class.
I have only 1 pojo in the application cause it is micro service.

Thanks.

Comment: hmmm this might be helpful or at least worth a read -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m

Comment: For now, you can probably work around the error with `--illegal-access=permit`. But whatever code that is trying to access that method should be fixed (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471466/what-to-use-instead-of-defineclass-in-java10)

Comment: I prefer to fix it cause I'm starting new project, do you know what I should change in the code, I have simple pojo

Comment: Are you using any libraries/frameworks?

Comment: Of course, springboot

Comment: Then it is the responsibility of Spring to fix the problem. Frameworks like that often define classes at run-time and ideally would have switched from `ClassLoader#defineClass(...)` to `Lookup#defineClass(....)` by now. Are you using the latest version of Spring Boot?

Comment: the parent in the pom file is 2.5.2

Answer (score 11):

You are using old versions of Spring / Spring Boot that are incompatible with, and do not support Java 16.

According to the [Spring Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions), you will need to use Spring 5.3.x or later for Java 16 compatibility.

For Spring-Boot, you need 2.7.1 or later for Java 17 compatibility ... according to this [Spring And Spring Boot Versions](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-and-spring-boot-versions) page.

Also note that Java 16 is end-of-life as well.  You probably should be using one of the LTS versions of Java; i.e. Java 8, 11, 17, 21 ...

<sup>(Winding back to an earlier Java LTS would "fix" the Spring compatibility issue, but IMO rolling Spring and Java forward is better.  You don't want to be developing a new project on top of a base that is *already* outdated.)</sup>

---

The actual problem you are seeing is due to something (probably a Spring Boot custom classloader) accessing an "internal" API.  This leads to warning messages since Java 9 and is blocked in Java 14 and later.  This Q&A gives some background:

- [How to solve InaccessibleObjectException ("Unable to make {member} accessible: module {A} does not 'opens {package}' to {B}") on Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266)

The simple and best solution is to use only "supported" versions of Java for your selected versions of Spring and Spring Boot.

Answer (score -2):

You can just define the JRE system library by precising the path following the next steps: Project Folder -> Properties -> Java build path -> double clicks on JRE system library and choose your installed JRE, it works for me.
And sorry for my bad English

Comment: It works for you because you are using an older version of Java ...