# Module java.base does not "opens java.lang"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Maven project, and somewhere in one of the 3rd-party dependencies (since it's only erroring when utilizing that functionality in the app), this error is being thrown:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 
threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final
java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) 
throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: 
module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @337d0578
```

I've tried adding these `--add-opens` arguments when starting the JAR, but it didn't make a difference, so I don't know if I'm doing it right, and I'm not really a Java developer, so I'm not sure how to add this to `pom.xml` or anything. Suggestions welcome.

`java -jar target\MyProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75116023/unable-to-make-protected-final-java-lang-class-java-lang-classloader-defineclass)

Comment: maybe change the order  of the options - from the [java command documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html): "`java [options] -jar jarfile [args ...]`"

Comment: I didn't think that changing the order would work, but it started and then gave a different error: ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/axway/passport/log/audit/jaxb/AuditMessage] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.axway.passport.log.audit.jaxb.AuditMessage`

Comment: @tevemadar: I don't think it does; I'm using IntelliJ like the top answer, but I don't know how to set that setting, as I'm also using maven, and then just trying to run the JAR from the command line. Also, I don't know how to tell what version of Java the app was initially written in.

Comment: do you have a jar file for com.axway.passport? I cannot find such dependency in maven, so you have to include manually, if you have

Comment: Note that the original problem is solved now. Although it's being clever after the fact, why the suggestion of @user85421 works is that arguments before the "program" (the jar file in this case) are meant for the Java runtime, the argumenst after it are meant for the program itself (and passed into the argument array of `main(String[] args)`). The new problem is different, the class in question is not in the classpath.